# Add a section in user properties using powershell in UPA sp2010

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, user-profile

I want to add a SECTION user property in UPA using powershell. I am executing the below script. It is executing for 1st time but getting error at ADD method in the second time.Also the property does not gets added

```
function CreateUserProfileSection()
{     
  $site = Get-SPSite $xmlData.UserProfileSection.SiteURL
  function Get-SPServiceContext([Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServiceApplication] $profileApp)
    {
     $profileApp = @(Get-SPServiceApplication | ? {$_.TypeName -eq "User Profile Service Application"})[0]
     return [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPServiceContext]::GetContext($profileApp.ServiceApplicationProxyGroup,[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSiteSubscriptionIdentifier]::Default)
    }
  $context = Get-SPServiceContext  
  $upcm = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileConfigManager($context);      
  $ppm = $upcm.ProfilePropertyManager
  $cpm = $ppm.GetCoreProperties()
  $ptpm = $ppm.GetProfileTypeProperties([Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileType]::User)
  $psm = [Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileSubTypeManager]::Get($context)
  $defaultSubType = [Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileSubtypeManager]::GetDefaultProfileName([Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileType]::User)
  $ps = $psm.GetProfileSubtype($defaultSubType)

  Write-Host "User Profile Objects setup complete"
  $Name = "testttttt"
  $pspm = $ps.Properties
  $Privacy1= "Public"
  $PrivacyPolicy1 ="Mandatory"
  $DisplayName1="Notifications Settings"
  $Description1 ="Custom2"
  #$xmlData.UserProfileSection.Section | ForEach-Object{
      $property = $pspm.GetSectionByName($Name)             
        if($property -eq $null)
        {
            $Privacy = $Privacy1
            $PrivacyPolicy=$PrivacyPolicy1
            $coreProp = $cpm.Create($true)
            $coreProp.Name = $Name
            $coreProp.DisplayName = $DisplayName1
            $coreProp.Description = $Description1


            $cpm.Add($coreProp)
            write-host -f green $_.Name section is created successfully             
        }
        else
        {
           write-host -f yellow $_.Name section already exists
        }
 #    }
 }

     #----------------Calling the function---------------------------------------------  
CreateUserProfileSection
```